# MS SQL - static sql query with dynamic filters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need an idea how to write a static sql query with dynamic input filters.

Example:

I have a table with list of product attributes with values like:

```
product_id | attr_name | value
==============================
1          | 'a'       | 1
1          | 'b'       | 3
1          | 'c'       | 1
```

let's say the name is **product_attribute**,

and i want to be able to search products using dynamic filters specified in a different table (named **search_filter**) like

```
name   | value
==============
'a'    |     1
'a'    |     2
'b'    |     3
'c'    |     1
'c'    |     4
```

so the query output will be the same like

```
SELECT product_id
FROM product_attribute
WHERE (attr_name = 'a' AND value IN (1,2)) -- LOGIC OR FOR VALUES
AND (attr_name = 'b' AND value IN (3))     -- LOGIC AND BETWEEN DIFFERENT ATTRIBUTES
AND (attr_name = 'c' AND value IN (1,4))
```

Any idea to achieve this without dynamicaly generated sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . does this work?

```
select pa.product_id
from product_attribute pa left join
     search_filter f
     on pa.attr_name = f.name
group by pa.product_id
having sum(case when pa.value = f.value then 1 else 0 end) = count(distinct f.name);
```